# Is there a required order of parameters in a swift function call

Tags: ios, json, xcode, syntax-error, parameter-passing

Xcode 8.3.3 is complaining about the order of parameters in my function declaration, as shown in the attached screen shot. The JSON info is shown in the panel below the code, and has data in the order:
autoplay, description, image, title, type, video, videoformat.

The error message says
Incorrect argument label in call (have 'title:description:image:video:type:autoplay.', expected 'title:description:image:video:videoformat:autoplay.')

In other words, Swift is expecting 'videoformat' instead of 'type'.
I don't care about videoformat and have not included it in the json serialization. I do care about type, and have a variable assigned for it, so I need to pass in a value.

[The current order of parameters has already been rigorously parsed by Xcode Swift - I originally had them in the order of declaration but Xcode/Swift insisted this order is required.]

Is it a coincidence that the required order is by parameter type:
String, String, URL, URL, ??, Int, and why is it asking for videoformat which has never been declared, but not for type which has been declared?
[Screenshot showing function declaration and actual json data to be parsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orFzI.png)

Comment: Show the code for your `Video` class? That is what's expecting the parameters...

Comment: Thanks DonMag. You are spot on - my class elsewhere in the code is what's defining the order.

Answer (score 1):

The order of parameters is either

(a) The order you specified in your init method

```
struct Video {
    let a: String
    let b: String

    init(a: String, b: String) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }
}
```

or

(b) the order they are declared in the struct, and you haven't defined an init method.

```
struct Video {
    let a: String
    let b: String
}
```

Here, the parameters are exactly as in (a), but Swift has created a default `init` method for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change order instead use default values if it's optional or not necessary at all time.

```
init(title: String, description: String, image: String, video: String, videoformat: String? = nil, autoplay: String? = nil) {
    self.title= title
    self.description= description
    self.image= image
    self.video= video
    self.videoformat= videoformat
    self.autoplay= autoplay
}
```

Now you can init like this now you no need to pass videoformat & other default params

```
Video(title: title, description: description, image: image, video: video, autoplay: autoplay)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is using the parameters correctly, but the error looks spurious, you should quit Xcode (normal way) and then re-launch.

This happened to me today where I was re-writting the code in several places at once. I interpret this as the indexer getting confused.

NOTE: I may have had to quit+launch twice before the problem was cleared away. I'm in Xcode 9.2, if that helps.